# Reading thousands of json file and process them using python multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I'm trying to read thousands of json file from directory and process each file separately and store the result in a dictionary. I already write a working code for sequential execution. Now i want to take the leverage of multi-processing for speed up the whole process.

So far what i did -

```
import json
import os
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def read_file(file_name):
    '''
        Read the given json file and return data
    '''
    
    with open(file_name) as file :
        data = json.load(file)
    
    return data

def do_some_process(data):
    '''
        Some calculation will be done here
        and return the result
    '''

    return some_result

def process_each_file(file, result):

    file_name = file.split('.')[0]    
    # reading data from file
    data = read_file('../data/{}'.format(file))
    processed_result = do_some_process(data)

    
    result[file_name] = processed_result


if __name__ == '__main__':


    manager = Manager()
    result = manager.dict()

    file_list = os.listdir("../data")
    
    all_process = [Process(target=process_each_file, args=(file, result, )) 
                  for file in file_list if file.endswith(".json")]
    

    for p in all_process:
        p.start() 
        
    for p in all_process:
        p.join() 

    '''
        Do some further work with 'rusult' variable
    '''
```

When i run this code it shows `OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files`

How can i achive my goal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read and process multiple JSON files using Python's multiprocessing module, you can use the following approach:

```
import os
import json
from multiprocessing import Pool

# List all the JSON files in the current directory
json_files = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if f.endswith('.json')]

def process_data(data):
    return data

def process_json_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        # Process the data here...
        processed_data = process_data(data)
        return processed_data

# Create a pool of workers to process the files concurrently
with Pool() as pool:
    # Apply the processing function to each JSON file concurrently
    results = pool.map(process_json_file, json_files)

# Do something with the results
for result in results:
    print(result)
```